# How do we tag questions with respect to a sport and its respective league?

Tags: discussion, tags

A question has been brought up in chat twice [(1)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/conversation/sport-league-tag-convo) [(2)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/conversation/sport-tag-convo-2) regarding the use of tags with respect to a sport and its respective league. It was asked both times if questions tagged with the league should also be tagged with the sport.

One perspective states: [sport] would be about the sport. [league] would be specific to the league.

Another perspective states: if the question is about [sport] rules, the tag [sport] fits, even if the question is specific to [league] rules.

**How do we tag questions with respect to a sport and its respective league** given the scenario presented above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag with the sport as well as the league. Let's say I'm interested in [cricket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cricket) questions, and have that as one of my favourite tags. If we don't tag *all* cricket questions with [cricket](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cricket), I've got to set all of the following as favourite tags (potentially. I appreciate most of these don't exist at the moment, but they could if we were tagging only with the league):

- [County Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Championship)
- [Royal London One-Day Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_London_One-Day_Cup)
- [Natwest t20 Blast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NatWest_t20_Blast)
- [Sheffield Shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffield_Shield)
- [Matador BBQs One-Day Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_domestic_limited-overs_cricket_tournament)
- [Big Bash League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bash_League)
- [Ranji Trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranji_Trophy)
- [Vijay Hazare Trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijay_Hazare_Trophy)
- [Indian Premier League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Premier_League)
- At least 3 more leagues in South Africa
- At least 3 more leagues in the West Indies
- At least 3 more leagues in New Zealand
- More leagues in Pakistan, Sri Lanka, Bangladesh and Zimbabwe.
- Any number of women's leagues
- Any number of leagues in the non-Test playing countries.
- Any number of lower level leagues.

The same problem exists for other sports: how many soccer competitions are there?

Comment: I agree. Tag with the league if necessary, but always tag with the sport.

Comment: I generally agree with this approach. The scenario I had in mind that wouldn't take this approach was a procedural question wrt a specific league. That's not necessarily about the sport. [Example](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/options-in-baseball).

Comment: I'd say adding the sport tag will improve the discoverability of the question, which is another of the real values of tags.